# Dynamic field type handling

Tags: .net, generics, oop, .net-2.0, csv

I have to do an export from DB to CSV. (**.NET 2**)

```
field; fileld; field... etc
```

Have 3 types of fields: **Alpha**, **Numeric** and **Bool** respresented as `"alphaValue"`,`intValue` and `True/False`.

I try to encapsulate this in a ***fields collection***, in order to export if alpha then set "", if Bool=>True/False if numeric let as is.

and try to build a `CsvField` class:

```
  Public Structure?Class CsvField(Of T As ???)

  End Structure

  Enum FieldType
    Alpha
    Bool
    Numeric
  End Enum
```

possibile usage:

```
myCollection.Add(new CsvField(DateTime.Now, FileType.Alpha))
myCollection.Add(new CsvField(myInt, FileType.Numeric))
```

any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No generics needed. Simply use inheritance:

```
' abstract base class; you could possibly declare it as an interface instead: '
MustInherit Class CsvField
    Public MustOverride Function Export() As String
End Class


' specialized class for alpha-numeric fields: '
Class AlphaCsvField : Inherits CsvField
    ...
    Public Overrides Function Export() As String
        Return String.Format("""{0}""", value)
    End Function

    Private value As String
End Class


' specialized class for bool fields '
Class BoolCsvField : Inherits CsvField
    ...
    Public Overrides Function Export() As String
        If value = True Then
            Return "True"
        Else
            Return "False"
        End If
    End Function

    Private value As Boolean
End Class

...
```

The code example assumes that `value` stores the actual value of a field. I hope this example is sufficiently clear. Make your fields collection one for type base class type, e.g. `List(Of CsvField)`. It can then contain objects of all derived types, too.

---

Btw., note how, when using [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), you might be able to get rid of the `FieldType` enumeration completely and all `If` / `Select Case` constructs that decide on what to do depending on the field type. If you still need to do that, you could replace:

```
If someCsvField.FieldType = Alpha Then ...
```

with

```
If TypeOf someCsvField Is AlphaCsvField Then ...
```

However, you should generally be able to move such logic into the derived classes and get rid of the `If` statements by overriding methods. This is the whole point of the above example.

---

**P.S.:** In case you're wondering how you create your `CsvField` objects without checking explicitly on the type. One way is to use factory methods and method overloading:

```
MustInherit Class CsvField

    Public Shared Function Create(value As String) As CsvField
        Return New AlphaCsvField(value)
    End 

    Public Shared Function Create(value As Boolean) As CsvField
        Return New BoolCsvField(value)
    End 

    ...

    ' as in the above code example '
    Public MustOverride Function Export() As String

End Class
```

For example, `CsvField.Create(False)` would create a `BoolCsvField` "disguised" as a `CsvField`, so that you can put it inside your `List(Of CsvField)` or whatever collection you have.

Comment: is the polymorphism more resources and time consuming that a simple class with type?

Comment: @serhio no, there's no resource or performance penalty when using inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: @serhio: No, or at least the additional *memory* overhead would be so small as to be insignificant in your case (most likely). Runtime *performance* might even improve very slightly. Don't worry about this. Using inheritance will result in better-structured, easier-to-read and thus more maintainable code, which is more important than a few additional used bytes in memory. If you're still interested in the reason for this, I can provide more details on demand.

Comment: why `Create(value As Boolean)` returns a `CsvField` and not a `BoolCsvField`?

Comment: @serhio: Because whoever calls the factory method should not need to be made aware of what exact type of `CsvField` is created. The important thing is that the caller will be able to get to the `Export` method through the returned object. Try to program against the generic "interface" provided by the abstract `CsvField` class as much as possible, because then you won't need to change your program if you'd later decide that you need a new field type. The program logic will only depend on the generic `CsvField` and not on any specific subclasses.